# No português europeu, é informal tratar um terceiro com o pronome “lo”?

Tags: português-europeu, informalidade, formalismo

Sou brasileiro e ouvi de outro brasileiro em Portugal que é informal dizer “ele” de um terceiro presente. Por exemplo, ao invés de “o professor está escrevendo na lousa”, dizer “ele está escrevendo na lousa”.

E tenho dúvida quanto ao pronome “lo”, se se encaixa na mesma questão. Por exemplo, dizer "vou acompanhá-lo", sobre um terceiro e não o ouvinte, seria informal? Deveria dizer "vou acompanhar o João"?

Comment: lo não é um sufixo. É um pronome pessoal direto. "Caso o verbo termine em -r, -s ou -z, essas consoantes são suprimidas e o pronome assume a forma “lo”, “la”, “los” ou “las”: https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/pronomes-pessoais-obliquos.html

Deve comprá-lo amanhã.//Então: acompanhar + lo = acompanhá-lo.

Comment: @Schilive The Student não reconheceu o pronome, dizendo que é "sufixo".

Comment: O meu comentário ficou porque não era tão rude como o teu. ;) Mas se o teu foi apagado, o meu fica sem sentido - vou removê-lo.